# What is a good way to display status of a file using Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist, imageicon

I want to do the following and I would need some suggestions on what is the best way to do it.

I have a JList which displays the files that the user adds by clicking add (+) button and removes the files when the user clicks remove (-) button. With each added file, I want to associate an icon which should indicate the status of the file. For example, if the user has only added the file and not run the file (I have another JButton for running the application with the selected file), then this icon should be red and once the user runs it, this icon should change to green. Also, if the user removes the file by clicking the (-) button, it should remove the icon associated with that particular file too.  Below is a pictorial representation of what I want.

I was thinking of associating a ImageIcon with each added file but I am not sure how to change its appearance to display the status. I am also not sure how the ImageIcon can be removed when the file is removed. Is there any other way (other than ImageIcon) to do it?  Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: *"I was thinking of associating a ImageIcon with each added file"* - Well, stop right there. Data is king. The UI just presents the data to the user in way which, hopefully looks nice.  Instead, you should have a "data" object which has a reference to the file and some kind of status, which can then be used (probably by a custom `ListCellRenderer`) to display the state. You can then use the `ListModel` to generate "change" events when ever the state has changed, or if you used a custom `ListModel` register a listener directly to the "data" object and have it tell you when it's changed

Comment: @Arvind Thank you for the suggestion! Can you please elaborate/ point me to an example?

Comment: @Silvermoon [How to use lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you for the suggestion, but I don't think I follow. I have just started Java and Swing programming. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Stultuske I know about JList and already have a GUI which adds and removes files. I was just wondering to implement this as a next step

Comment: @Stultuske I completely agree but I was thinking a good way to understand programming would be to do so by implementing it. But I totally agree with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In programming, data is king.  How that data get's represented should not be of consideration to the data, that's the domain/responsibility of the UI/view layers.

This is often represented by the [model-view-controller pattern](https://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/)

In your example, you have two pieces of (basic) information.  A file and a status (not run, run, deleted), you want to combine this information as "data".  In Java, that typically means a Plain Old Java Object (or Pojo)

Because the status only has a limited number of possibilities, we can use a `enum` to represent it, and thereby restricting the valid values

```
public enum FileStatus {
    NOT_RUN, RUN, DELETED;
}
```

And then we can create our own pojo...

```
public class FileOperation {
    private File file;
    private FileStatus status;

    public FileOperation(File file, FileStatus status) {
        this.file = file;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public FileOperation(File file) {
        this(file, FileStatus.NOT_RUN);
    }

    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public FileStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(FileStatus newStatus) {
        if (status == newStatus) {
            return;
        }
        this.status = newStatus;
    }

}
```

Now, when we want to know the status of the file, we know where to get it.

But what about the `JList`? You ask, good question.  What we really want is some way that the `JList` can be informed when the status of any `FileOperation` object changes.

Now, you could iterate over the `ListModel`, but that's not a very clean solution, a better solution is to allow the `FileOperation` to generate events when it changes and have the `ListModel` listen for them and take it's own action.

This is a basic concept of an [observer pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm)ƒ

There's a number of ways you might do this, but I'm lazy, so I'm just going to use the available property change API

```
public class FileOperation {
    private File file;
    private FileStatus status;

    private PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    public FileOperation(File file, FileStatus status) {
        this.file = file;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public FileOperation(File file) {
        this(file, FileStatus.NOT_RUN);
    }

    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public FileStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(FileStatus newStatus) {
        if (status == newStatus) {
            return;
        }
        FileStatus oldStatus = status;
        status = newStatus;
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("status", oldStatus, status);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }
}
```

And now we need a `ListModel` which can respond to it...

```
public class FileOperationListModel extends AbstractListModel<FileOperation> {

    private List<FileOperation> items = new ArrayList<FileOperation>(25);
    private PropertyChangeListener handler = new PropertyChangeHandler();

    public void add(FileOperation fo) {
        fo.addPropertyChangeListener(handler);
        int size = items.size();
        items.add(fo);
        fireIntervalAdded(this, size, size);
    }

    public void remove(FileOperation fo) {
        int index = items.indexOf(fo);
        if (index < 0) {
            return;
        }
        fo.removePropertyChangeListener(handler);
        items.remove(fo);
        fireIntervalRemoved(this, index, index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public FileOperation getElementAt(int index) {
        return items.get(index);
    }

    public class PropertyChangeHandler implements PropertyChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if (!(evt.getSource() instanceof FileOperation)) {
                return;
            }
            FileOperation fo = (FileOperation) evt.getSource();
            int index = items.indexOf(fo);
            fireContentsChanged(FileOperationListModel.this, index, index);
        }

    }

}
```

Now, the final piece of the puzzle, is you're going to need a custom `ListCellRenderer` which can display the information you want.

For that, you're going to have to start by reading [How to use lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer)